# Previewing the look of your instant article in the browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I'm developing an FB Instant articles CMS (using the PHP sdk) for a news company. One of their requests is the following:

they want to be able to preview the look of the actual article on a mobile device inside of their CMS before publishing it.

As of now I haven't found a way to tackle this so I'm wondering if anyone else has had the same problem?

Comment: Don’t know of any way to directly integrate that into a CMS. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/get-started/test-and-debug refers to a _Facebook Pages Manager_ app for iPhone or Android, that can be used to preview IA.

Comment: I'm familiar with the Facebook Pages Manager app and I'm already able to test and preview Instant Articles with it. However, the client wants to have the preview of the instant article inside their CMS. Thanks anyway! P.S. Right now I'm looking at the code of a wordpress plugin from PageFrog that has the ability to show the actual look of an FB-IA inside a browser.

Answer (score 0):

The end solution was to simply simulate the look and feel of Instant Articles with CSS and  [display it in a div that looks like a phone (click for pic).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8rZo.png)